# How to update C3.js graph line width and tick color?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, c3.js

How to update the default line width in a C3.js graph? How to update the tick (the circles) color?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you use a DOM inspector you can see what classes the different objects have and then it's just a case of [assigning some CSS to them](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/7kYJu/1021/) e.g.

```
.c3-line {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

.c3-circle {
    fill: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For case of increasing scatterplot circle radius, radius of circles on line charts.
Please use like this:

```
c3.generate({
...
  point: {
    r: 10,
  },
...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation you can control line width individually by following

```
[chart-id] .c3-line-[chart-data-name] {
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```

if it does not work try to use `!important`

ex:

```
#chart .c3-line-data2 {
  stroke-width: 5px;
}
```