# Adjust line thickness of c3 plot from R

Tags: r, c3.js

I wish to increase the thickness of line graphs in c3

Shiny App

```
library(shiny)
library(c3)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(theme = "my.css",
               c3Output("chart")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$chart <- renderC3({
    c3(iris)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In the same directory as this Shiny app, I have created a www directory which contains "my.css"

my.css

```
.c3-line {
  width: 2px;
}

.c3-chart-lines {
  width: 2px;
}
```

My guesses as to the correct css did not work. I also tried `stroke-width` according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296535/how-to-update-c3-js-graph-line-width-and-tick-color) which also did not work.

How do I adjust the line width of line charts created with c3 from R?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
.c3-line {
  stroke-width: 3px !important; 
}
```